# PHPUnit does nothing Gitlab-ci

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When Gitlab-ci execute the script : `php vendor/phpunit/phpunit --colors --verbose --configuration phpunit.xml`

PHPUnit seems to do nothing this is the output from Gitlabci :

```
$ php vendor/phpunit/phpunit --colors --verbose --configuration phpunit.xml
Job succeeded
```

I've tried with no option for PHPUnit and it's still the same i don't understand why, it's working properly on my local

I'm working with the framework Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed phpunit with composer and haven't changed the bin-dir configuration, the path to phpunit is `vendor/bin/phpunit`:

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You should also be able to simply call the phpunit script directly:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Assuming your current working directory is the root of your project.

Comment: Yes thank you it's finally working with the php ./vendor/bin/phpunit